# How to use fuzzywuzzy's process.extract function to process a list of objects by a particular attribute?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have created an object called `Issuer`, which contains a member named `issuer_name`.

I want to take advantage of fuzzywuzzy's `process.extract()` function, but it only takes in a list of strings. My goal is to find matches and return the list of objects that match by the `issuer_name`.

I came up with this method below, but it's running really slow. The issuers list contains over 100,000 elements.

```
# (string, list of issuers , integer)
def fuzzyMatchWordToIssuers(word, issuers, threshold):
    limit = 5
    count = 0
    res = []
    for issuer in issuers:
        calc = fuzz.token_set_ratio(word,issuer.issuer_name)
        if calc >= threshold:
            res.append(issuer)
            count += 1
        if count == limit:
            return res
    return res
```

Is it possible to use the `process.extract()` somehow, or speed this up?

For reference, here's the github example:

```
process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface**

My solution was tested for correctness. I need to be able to search on a list of objects and that is the solution that worked for me. However, my solution was not tested for performance, nor do I care about it since my data sets are rather small. For large datasets I strongly recommend using a 3rd party tool, probably some cloud based search tool will be scalable and with reasonable performance.

**Solution**

fuzzywuzzy process.extract apparently can handle a dictionary where only values are being searched and the result is a list of tuples with the following structure

```
(query, score, key)
```

Where `query` and `score` are the same as using extract with lists and `key` is the key that matched the string value (values must still be strings only).
So, you will need to create a processed issuer names dictionary with keys as indexes like so

```
issuer_names_dict = dict(enumerate([issuer.name for issuer in issuers]))
```

Then you can pass this dictionary to `process.extract` (I think you should use extractBests since you are using a cutoff threshold)

```
best_issuers = process.extractBests(word, issuer_names_dict, score_cutoff=threshold, limit=5)
```

Finally you will need to assemble the result list

```
res = [issuers[z] for (x,y,z) in best_issuers]
```